# How to manage a database with branches and trunk like SVN

Tags: postgresql, svn, version-control, merge

I have a project for a web application developed in java using a database in postgres 9.4, for versioning of code we use SVN, creating branches for changes in the project and when the change is ready and tested is merge to the trunk having a working project without errors.

Now, the problem is that the database is unique and is not versioned, and we make the changes directly into a single database and then if we want to use it for the trunk version may be errors because the database has changes which are not yet implemented in the trunk version.

We tried to work on a copy of the database along with the branches but what happened to us is that after change we don't always update the DB trunk so we generated errors.

Is there any way to include the database changes in SVN?
How could be the best way to handle these changes?

Comment: Have you considered using views?

Comment: i already use database views and functions. Is there other type of views?

Comment: I mean that if you need the same data for all revisions of your application, you could create a view of the tables for each different revision. Another option would be using a separate database for each of the branches.

Comment: i try it but i end up with so many views when only one is valid, because of this the database structure become dirty. if i use separates databases how i can merge the change into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a tool that allows you to manage migration files. for instance i'm thinking about phing.

[Here](https://www.phing.info/trac/wiki/Users/Documentation) is the doc.
[Here](http://davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy.html) is an example.

Hope this will help